# Why don't I see all local variables in debugger?

Tags: intellij-idea

There is some clever logic, which evaluates, which variables are interesting for me, or maybe there is some other reason, however I cannot see all local variables in variables pane. Is there some switch which would allow me to see all variables, instead of hovering cursor over time(time consuming + mouse usage)?

Thanks

Comment: What language do you debug? Does it help if you disable the [Auto-Variables](https://i.imgur.com/56yHi5X.png) mode option?

Comment: java. I did not know about auto-variables mode. Thanks, based on this name I was able to find it. I'm not sure if it will fix my issue, as I terminated rather complex session where it happened to me, but it seems to summon some missing variables.

Comment: I've linked a screenshot in the comment, so it should be no problem to find this setting.